# org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError

Tags: hibernate

tx=session.beginTransaction();
        ***Query q=session.createQuery("update Product as p set p.quantity=:n where p.id=:i");***
        q.setParameter("n",1000);
        q.setParameter("i",11);

```
    int status=q.executeUpdate();  
    System.out.println(status);
```

***I am getting following Exception when I execute above code in hibernate***

Sep 02, 2015 5:23:46 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR: line 1:8: unexpected token: in
Sep 02, 2015 5:23:46 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR: line 1:8: unexpected token: in
line 1:8: unexpected token: in
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.updateStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:239)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:295)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1836)
    at in.edu.pondiuni.service.ProductIssuedService.deleteFromProduct(ProductIssuedService.java:41)
    at in.edu.pondiuni.controller.ProductIssuedServlet.processRequest(ProductIssuedServlet.java:78)
    at in.edu.pondiuni.controller.ProductIssuedServlet.doGet(ProductIssuedServlet.java:90)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Comment: Thats strange error says "unexpected token: in at ", but your query doesn't have any token "in",  you have somewhere "in" token but you cant use it as its a keyword. And also check if your tokens are typed correctly like if "i" is long you must do like this q.setParameter("i",(long)11);

Comment: Mr. Anudeep I tried q.setParameter("i",(long)11); but it's not working too..

Comment: I am not getting any problem in insert and select but getting the problem in updation... Do you know what does this exception means...

Comment: yes its unable to find the token : which is strange, may be you have different hibernate version..Try without alias "update Product  set quantity = :prodQty where id = :productId" , set your parameters types correctly..if productId is mapped as long, then setParameter("productId",(long)11)....

Comment: If it still doesn't work try binding parameters with positions like "update Product set quantity = ? where id = ? " and setParameter(0, 1000); setParameter(1, (long)11);

Comment: yet. the same problem              And getting one more exception Updation Problem java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!

Comment: I am using Hibernate4.3.10,  tomcat 7.0 and oracle 10g

Comment: Post Product entity and hibernate mapping file

Comment: ..........................hibernate.cfg.xml......................

Comment: <property name="hibernate.connection.password">manager</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>  
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <mapping class="in.edu.pondiuni.model.User" /> 
        <mapping class="in.edu.pondiuni.model.Product"/>
        <mapping class="in.edu.pondiuni.model.ProductIssued"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>

Comment: .........Product.java..........

Comment: dont post in the comments, post on your question

Answer (score 0):

This is an open bug, HQL query fails if entity is inside a package which starts with "in" or "by". For your reference [view this link](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11784) .

You can work around by adding the entity-name attribute in your hbm.xml as below.

```
<class name="in.package.Entity" entity-name="Entity" table="MY_TABLE">
```